# sparkR to query & retrieve StructField name from StructType

Tags: parquet, sparkr

I have a parquet file with the structure below.

```
message sample_date {
  optional group A {
    optional binary rowkey (UTF8);
    optional binary key (UTF8);
    optional binary value (UTF8);
  }

  optional group B {
    optional binary rowkey (UTF8);
    optional binary comment (UTF8);
  }
}
```

In sparkR, I can read in the parquet file as:

`pqfile <- read.parquet(sqlContext, "/user/sample_data.parquet)`

Then create a dataframe for each group, for example, for group B

`groupB <- select(pqfile, "B")`

The schema for groupB is StructType and fields within groupB is StructField.

Is there any way that I can retrieve the field name (rowkey and comment) from dataframe groupB?

If I run columns(df), I only get one column name "B". I couldn't find any method to query and retrieve 
the field names within the StructType.

Any help is greatly appreciated!